# How to implement a multithreaded infinite-task with subthreads in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

Inside my Rails 4 application I need to make API calls to a webservice where I can ask for an instance of stock quotes. I can ask for 1000 stocks in one request and four requests at a time which is the throttle limit.

The workflow goes like this:
A user makes a request to my app and wants to get quotes for 12000 stocks.

So I chunk it into twelve requests and put them in a Queue.
At application start I start a thread in a loop which is supposed to look at the queue and since I am allowed to make concurrent requests I'd like to make 4 requests in parallel.

I get stuck in several ways. First of all I need to take into consideration that I can get multiple requests of 12000 stocks at a time since different users can trigger the same request.

Second, I ll use the Thin web server wjich is multithreaded. So I guess I have to use a Mutex.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm curious, what webservice are you using to get the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queues are already threadsafe data structures, so you don't need a mutex to work with them.

You'd just start 4 threads at the start of your app, which each poll the queue for work, do some work, and then do something (which is up to you) to notify the DB and/or user that the work is complete. The actual workers will be something like:

```
work_queue = Queue.new
4.times do 
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      job = work_queue.pop
      # Do some work with the job
    end
  end
end
```

`Queue#pop` blocks until data is available, so you can just fire off those queues and the first thread waiting for data will get the job when it's pushed in, the next thread will get the next job, and so on. While there are no worker threads available, jobs will accumulate in the queue.

What you actually do with the output of the job is probably the more interesting question here, but you haven't defined what should happen when the quotes are retrieved.

You might also look at [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This script could run in an initializer of rails, but since thin webserver is multithreaded I guess that this script will load each time thins loads the app right? And consequently I have more than 4 threads, or is queue threadsafe eventhough it s getting accessed by another rails instance ?    Regarding the result: As long as I am processing the 12000 quotes the user should get the results and additionally the client should get a status signaling to the client that he needs to keep on polling. Sidekiq looks great but batch support is only in pro license available.

Comment: If you need a hard concurrency limit of 4, then you either need to use an IPC lock or a separate runner like Sidekiq, to accomodate multiple potential instances of the application (ie, on multiple machines, when you scale out horizontally). You could trivially impose a 4-job currency limit by using Redis to acquire and release resource locks (ie, via BLPOP and PUSH)

Comment: In the same process, yes. Across processes, no. (Well technically, you could use dRB, but I don't recommend it)

Comment: Thin starts 1 instance per process, which can then process requests in a multi-threaded fashion. I think you're confusing multithreading with multiprocess deployments.

Comment: Yes, as long as you only have one process running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80438/discussion-between-dc10-and-chris-heald).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I took a look into sidekiq and i'd prefer to use a lib which abstracts threads handling. So what I treat is passing a queue into a worker, but that does not work. I stumbled upon this gem https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch which does exactly what I need. Here I can start a worker with a limit just for this queue   Sidekiq::Queue[:test].limit = 4 . I guess this is it..